# INI file reverse engineering

Tags: string, printing, reverse-engineering, barcode

I am maintaining a legacy application which prints product labels on packaging. The format of the label is stored in a INI file. I wanted to know if anyone has any hints about the meaning of this format. I have pasted a snippet here.

`{D1531,1000,1501|}
{C|}
{U2;0130|}
{D1531,1000,1501|}
{AX;+000,+000,+00|}
{AY;+05,0|}
{PC000;0922,0555,15,15,H,11,B|}
{RC00;<FE/>LABELTITLE</FE>|}
{PC001;0865,0555,15,15,H,11,B|}
{RC01;<FE/>CURRENT</FE>|}
{PC002;0796,0040,10,10,H,11,B|}`

Comment: You'll really need to look at more than one snippet. Compare a few snippets along with changes in the actual format to tie the changes in the format to parts of the .ini file that change with them. Alternatively, modify some specific parts of the ini file, and watch how that affects the output.

Comment: Some may refer to printer specific codes, so I would suggest looking at the printer documentation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is printer commands for Century Eagle barcode label printer. 
jai Ho!

Comment: you should give credit to jgc @ HN for working it out  (http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1346961)

Answer (score 0):

Use the source code. :-)   That will get you somewhere faster than reading the input to a program and trying to deduce the content of the code from the input to that code.

Comment: unfortunately source code is not with us. The vendor who supplied this software has vanished with sc.